# Vue.js historyapifallback not working, Why?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, webpack-dev-server

In the development environment, refreshing from /test works fine.

However, when I refresh after deployment, I get a 404 error.

Where is the problem?

vue.config.js

```js
const path = require("path");
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    overlay: false,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
  },
  transpileDependencies: [
    'element-plus'
  ],
  
  publicPath: '/',
  
  outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
}
```

Comment: `devServer.historyApiFallback` only configures your dev server. This has no effect on your production server. You have to configure your production server to redirect to `index.html`.

Comment: Do I need to make modifications on the server instead of in Vue.js's Webpack?

Comment: Yes. The production server needs to be configured.